# Deleted products still showing on my website

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin

I really need help.
I have deleted some products on my admin panel but it still shows on my website.
and when I try to add new products they don't show on the website either,
is there something i'm doing wrong?
I have followed all the steps to delete and add products strictly but still
please help.

Comment: Did you enable cache

Comment: I too have the same problem. the deleted products are only visible on the website. the new products are not showing. i have tried the re-indexing and refreshing cache options too. but it is not resolved as yet. Using magento ver. 2.2.3

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134270)

Answer (score 2):

Rerun indexing and refresh all caches.  I;m sure someone can comment on specifically "which" caches and "which" indexes, but usually on small stores its fine to flush all.

Comment: It's reindex and cache problem only. clear cache management and put reindex for Category Products and  Catalog URL Rewrites or put reindex that's best

Comment: Thanks.  I cleared my cache and put  reindex as directed and it worked.

Comment: Great!  If you can accept my answer as correct I'll get the points for it!  Thanks!